# elm post json to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5, elm

I exploring Elm and Rails Api as server.
Getting data from Rails is easy but how to POST.

There is a table scores in Rails scores.json:

```
[
  {
  id: 1,
  name: "Larry",
  score: 100
  }
]
```

In Elm I have de/encode

```
scoreDecoder : Decoder Score
scoreDecoder =
Decode.map3 Score
    (field "id" Decode.int)
    (field "name" Decode.string)
    (field "score" Decode.int)


encodeScore : Model -> Encode.Value
encodeScore model =
    Encode.object
    [ ("name", Encode.string model.name)
    , ("score", Encode.int (sumMarkedPoints model.entries))
    ]
```

and a command:

```
postScore : Model -> Cmd Msg
postScore model =
let
    url =
        "http://localhost:3000/scores"

    body =
        encodeScore model
            |> Http.jsonBody

    request =
        Http.post url body scoreDecoder
in
    Http.send NewScore request
```

I have button sending a Msg: ShareScore

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
ShareScore ->
        ( model, postScore model )
```

and I get:
Error posting your score: BadStatus { status = { code = 400, message = "Bad Request" }, headers = Dict.fromList [("content-type","application/json; charset=UTF-8")], url = "http://localhost:3000/scores", body = "{\"status\":400,\"error\":\"Bad Request\",\"exception\":\"#\u003cActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty:

Need some help to 'decode' that..

```
def score_params
  params.require(:score).permit(:id, :name, :score)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that `Rails` expects your input to be something like:

```
{
  score: {  
    name: "Larry",
    score: 100
  }
}
```

But you're passing just `{ name: "Larry", score: 100 }`, thus required `score` key is missing.

One of the options is to enhance your encoder into something like:

```
encodeScore : Model -> Encode.Value
encodeScore model =
    Encode.object
        [ ( "score"
          , Encode.object
                [ ( "name", Encode.string model.name )
                , ( "score", Encode.int (sumMarkedPoints model.entries) )
                ]
          )
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks so far. I changed also:
 [ ( "name", Encode.string model.name )
                , ( "score", Encode.int (sumMarkedPoints model.entries) )
                ]
Now Rails complaines: Bad payload"http://localhost:3000/scores", body = "{\"id\":null,\"name\":\"Mike\",\"score\":220}" }

Comment: ok I made it ..it looks like the was a name conflict table model.score&&item.score. After renaming to points..works..thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Avoid name confict..

```
 encodeScore : Model -> Encode.Value
 encodeScore model =
    Encode.object
     [ ( "score"
      , Encode.object
            [ ( "name", Encode.string model.name )
            , ( "points", Encode.int (sumMarkedPoints 
                model.entries) )
            ]
      )
    ]
```